# Plesk PHP API copy domain files

Tags: php, plesk

I've been meddling with the Plesk panel PHP api.

It works through sending XML packets to the server.
So far, I've figured out how to create a database. It works like this:

```
<packet>
  <database>

    <add-db>
      <webspace-id>$webspaceID</webspace-id>
      <name>testDB</name>
      <type>mysql</type>
    </add-db>

  </database>
</packet>
```

Though it would be ideal to run a preset .sql file the moment the database is created, I can actually just run this with PHP so that's not a real problem ( It'd just be nicer)

Anyway, with this, I also want to create a new subdomain. (Which isn't so different from the above)

Now, however, I'd like to have `example.mywebsite.com` as an example website to copy the files from and move them to this domain.

Does anybody know how I can copy the entire domain into the new one through the Plesk api, or if it is even possible?

Now, if this is not possible, would you have any suggestions of how to pick this up with PHP? (Maybe use `curl` to download a `.zip` file from the example domain and extract it or something?)

This is all quite new to me, so some advice would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: First, my obligatory "Plesk/cPanel/etc. suck and you're better off without them". Second, https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/cli-linux/using-command-line-utilities/skeleton-virtual-host-templates.40784/ is probably what you want. Not sure if it exists in the API.

Comment: @ceejayoz Well, I'm not experienced enough with commandline servers to do this without it, unfortunately ;) -- Thanks for the docs, but I couldn't really find anything about moving files in it, so that's why I asked :) (Maybe I'm not looking for the right keywords?)

Comment: It is not possible to clone domain through API. But https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/api-rpc/reference/managing-subdomains/creating-subdomain.53475/#o53493 describes how to create a subdomain. And https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/api-rpc/reference/uploading-files-to-server.36040/ provides instructions on how to upload files. There are also sample PHP script available from there. Also you can find useful examples here https://github.com/plesk/api-examples